# What's the quickest way to connect a Bluetooth audio device in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, audio, bluetooth, connection

Whenever I connect a Bluetooth audio device I currently do

1. Control Panel
2. Bluetooth Devices
3. Bluetooth Configuration
4. Audio tab
5. Connect

Which is a bit of a pain. The best I've managed to do is to have a shortcut on the desktop directly for step 2.

Isn't there a faster way?

Best would be to make Windows recognize when the audio device has been turned on and prompt for action, but I don't dream to get that far.

Answer (score 1):

When your bluetooth is truned on, you should see a Bluetooth icon on system tray. Click it and you should see the option "Allow a device to connect".. try it.. if doesn't work, the press "Show Bluetooth devices" then select device and connect.

Answer (score 1):

There's another shorter way,

Goto start menu and type bluetooth in the search box at the bottom of the start menu. Then a search result named "Change Bluetooth Settings" will appear. Drag it and Drop it on the desktop. It'll create a shortcut to the bluetooth settings dialog.

Answer (score 1):

When you have added a bluetooth device once, it should show up when you open / type:
*view devices and printers*

Over there you can right click on your speaker / headset and click:
*Advanced Operation* -> *connect to audio device*